# Highlight cell in my side bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've created a side bar (like the facebook app) and everything works fine. One thing though is that I want the cell in my Table View (basically the sidebar) to be highlighted if that's the view currently active.

I have no idea how to do this. I though I could do this in the IB almost like a button where there are options for the different states but this is not the case.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean set the cell selected? or you want to change the selection color?

Comment: Yes the cell selected

Answer (score 1):

You can create subclass of the UITableViewCell and override method setSelected:

```
- (void) setSelected: (BOOL) selected animated: (BOOL) animated
{
    [super setSelected: selected
              animated: animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

If you need set selected cell you can do it programmatically:

```
[myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in the function which activates the View:

```
int index = activeViewIndex;

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:activeViewIndex inSection: 0];
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```